# MS IME 15.0 JP - default entry to half-width instead of full-width

Tags: windows-registry, ime

In the previous IME versions, MS offered an option to choose half-width alphanumeric entry in the default setting, as no sane person uses full-width unless you are working for the Japanese government. However, the IME 15.0 does not have the option to access those settings yet, so I intend to take a dive into the registry.

I've narrowed down to the suspicious directory in the registry as shown below, but I cannot figure out what values should be entered to adjust these to half-width.

```
Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\IME\15.0\IMEJP\MSIME\AutoCharWidth
```